# tastypie hydrate() not getting called

Tags: tastypie

I am new to tastypie. I have a tastypie model resource where I want to use hydrate() to take serialized data from the client and turn it into a proper format that the data model can use. I have tried hydrate() hydrate_foo() but it seems all the hydrate() functions are not getting called, while dehydrate() will always get called. In my resource model, there're also obj_get(), obj_update(). Are there restrictions/constraints as to how the hydrate() function should be defined in the resource model so that I could use it to manipulate data submitted by the client?

Comment: you should attach some of the code

Answer (score 0):

I know this post is pretty old but, since documentation and examples on Tastypie are very limited, I'm adding my small experience here.

Without code it is hard to give a proper answer but I've seen that hydrate methods are only called if we explicitly call in the obj_create function the full_hydrate method as follows:

```
bundle = self.full_hydrate(bundle)
```

I thought they were automatically called by Tastypie but it seems not the case.